# css not work on code pen => *, *::before, *::after

Tags: css, codepen

I do not why ?

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

code pen is not work

https://codepen.io/hujisawa/pen/rrKXNY

my git lab is work

https://gitlab.com/Ryosuke-Hujisawa/github-login-sns-button

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
<style type="text/css">
```

and

```
</style>
```

and it should work.